# How to implement layoutSubviews of superclass for navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to override layoutSubviews for the Navigation Bar as per this example here, but I do not know how.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80075

I can get a reference to the navigationItem with self.navigationItem, however I am unsure on how to handle the layoutSubviews event I need in order to make some changes to the layout of the NavigationBar.

```
class ArticleViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

  override func layoutSubviews() {
         //Compiler doesn't like this - Method does not override any method from its superclass
  } }
```

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80075

Answer (score 0):

`layoutSubviews` is a method on `UIView` but you have a `UIViewController`.  The corresponding method on `UIViewContoller` is [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews).  You need to decide what level you want to handle layout at, in the UIView or in the UIViewController.  In most cases you can do it either way.  If you want the customized functionality to be used across many ViewControllers it makes more sense to do it at the UIView level.